# Parallel/multithreading version of linear regression in Julia

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, julia, regression, distributed-computing

I implemented regression model with interactions using Julia `GLM` package:

`Reg = lm(@formula(dep_var ~ var1&var2&var3), data, true)`.

Fitting this formula requires a lot of RAM (> 80 GB), but I noticed that the calculations are performed on one core, although my OS (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) has 8 cpu cores.

**Is it possible to implement linear regression using multiprocessing/parallelism approaches?**

I suppose, it could also improve the model runtime.

Comment: On my machine, BLAS operations performed by Julia have always been multi-threaded by default. That is, I've never had to change any environment variables. Is it possible something else about your computation is causing the issue? Is your RAM maxing out at any point? Does your machine start using Swap? Perhaps try a smaller matrix operation, say, inverting a `5000 x 5000` matrix and see if your machine only uses one core then.

Answer (score 2):

Fitting a regression model is basically doing lots of matrix operations. By default Julia is using BLAS and the easiest thing you can do is to try to configure it to be multi-threaded. This requires running Julia in a multi-threaded setting *and* setting the `BLAS.set_num_threads()` configuration.

Before starting Julia run:

```
set JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4
```

or on Linux

```
export JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4
```

Once Julia is started run the command.

```
BLAS.set_num_threads(4)
```

You should observe an increased performance of your linear regression models.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I tried your recommendation but unfortunately the `BLAS.set_num_threads(4)` didn't work for me - still only one cpu core is used and zabbix monitoring shows an increase in memory usage. Also, model runtime increased by about one minute.

Comment: Interestingly, I've never needed to do this on my machines. Julia code that performs BLAS operation has always been multi-threaded by default...